# Prove that $\mathcal{P}(A) = \mathcal{P}(B) \iff A = B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

I tried to prove this theory, but I wasn't really sure with my proof. Any help/advice?

I tried to prove as such:

$\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the Power Set of $A$

($\Rightarrow$) Assume $A = B$

Then $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$

If $A \subseteq B$ then $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$

If $B \subseteq A$ then $\mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$

Thus $\mathcal{P}(A) = \mathcal{P}(B)$

---

($\Leftarrow$) Assume $\mathcal{P}(A) = \mathcal{P}(B)$

Then $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$ and $\mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$

If $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$ then $A \subseteq B$

If $\mathcal{P}(B) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A)$ then $B \subseteq A$

Thus $A = B$

I'm really not sure about my proof so I would be happy if someone could prove it better or explain if there is a problem with my proof...

Comment: What is $\mathcal{P}(A)$? The power set of $A$?

Comment: Yes, its is. I'll update that... Sorry for not clarifying that

Comment: Well.. basically, yes, your solution is right. But can you elaborate why $\mathcal P(A)\subseteq\mathcal P(B)$ implies $A\subseteq B$? I think that's the main point here.

Comment: That is part of a different proof, which I got to proof one question before this one... So I simply refer to that in my work... If this is right then I basically only refer to previous proofs if needed, I just wasn't sure about my proof, if it was correct...

Comment: Then, using that one, this proof is perfect.

Comment: Rather than saying "if $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$ then $A \subseteq B$", it would be clearer to say "because $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$, we can conclude that $A \subseteq B$". The problem with the former way of saying things is that it doesn't make it clear that the statements "$\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$" and "$A \subseteq B$" are *true*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is correct; but perhaps it would be better to clarify why $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B) \iff A \subseteq B$.

Comment: Ok thanks, I proved this in a previous question so I'll just refer to that... Thanks!

Comment: A set is determined by its greatest subset.

Answer (score 3):

There is a unique maximal element of each of those sets when they are ordered by inclusion. In one it is $A$ in the other it is $B$. But then if the two powersets are equal their maximal elements must be as well, so $A=B$.

Answer (score 2):

The direction $A=B$ implies $P(A)=P(B)$ is trivial by definition of power sets. For the other direction, suppose $A\neq B$. All you need to show is $P(A)\neq P(B)$. Now let $x\in A\Delta B$ and consider $\{x\}$.

Comment: Ok, that is a great way to prove also... But does it shorten the proof? I mean you could just do what I did or do your way, it might shorten it, but as long as mine is fine I'm good with that... Thanks for sharing another way to think about it though, I might use it in other proofs!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $\mathcal P(A) = \mathcal P(B)$. We have $A \in \mathcal P(A) \implies A \in \mathcal P(B) \implies A\subset B$. Similarly $B\subset A$ $\therefore A = B$.

Answer (score 0):

For the other direction, If $\mathcal P(A) \subseteq \mathcal P(B)$ then for if $x \in A\implies \{x\} \in \mathcal P(A)\implies \{x\} \in \mathcal P(B)\implies x \in B \implies A \subseteq B$, and similarly $B \subseteq A$. So $A = B$.

Comment: Thanks I'll use that as it doesn't require additional proofs, so it will be easier to proof during the test... Thanks mate!